# change max-width if text goes out

Tags: jquery, html

i've got a problem but i can't seem to find a solution

Okay, i got 1 div example 12.5% x 12.5% *(This needs to be 12.5)*.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="liins">Insert Lorem</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    background-color: RGB(211, 211, 211);
    position: absolute;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    float: left;
    min-width: 12.5%;
    min-height: 12.5%;
    max-width: 12.5%;
    max-height: 12.5%;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#liins").click(function() {
    $(".div").append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>Sed ut fringilla neque. <br>Nam luctus gravida urna sed congue. <br>Quisque semper neque ac augue mollis, vel volutpat libero sodales. <br>In pulvinar auctor lacus, vitae auctor nisi. <br>Ut congue iaculis fringilla. Curabitur varius posuere enim non porta. <br>Cras enim nisl, tempus sit amet odio vel, commodo pellentesque magna. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>Donec enim arcu, feugiat a dictum vel, congue non arcu. <br>Duis quis dapibus sapien. Nulla sit amet diam nec ipsum pulvinar faucibus nec sed odio.");
});
```

What i want:
if the button appended the lorem ipsum the text doesn't need to overflow,
instead of overflowing JQuery needs to add 12.5% height until the text is not overflowing.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/flowwdelapro/pen/PyvRPE)

Comment: why add a height if you want it to grow?

Comment: @Pete it has no use but I guess it's an assignment

Comment: sorry the height needs to be min-height 12.5; and max-height: 12.5; if text overflows he needs to set min-height to 25; and max-height to 25; or if more text inserted to 37.5%

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you could look into flexbox and the flex property as well as the justify-content and align-X properties

Comment: okay i have 8 blocks each block is 12.5% so 100% is full blocks(100% from top to bottom in HTML). So if people type more then 12.5% the 12.5% needs to be + on max-height.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in jQuery

```
var counter = 1;

$("#liins").click(function() {

  counter++;

    $(".div").css("max-height") == 12.5*parseInt(counter);
});
```

Comment: i need a max-height  of 12.5% all the time that's the whole thing.

Comment: Then use .div{overflow:scroll;}

Comment: no that's not the idea i need to add 12.5% to the max-width with JQuery.